# How to edit a resource file from within an android app? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating an android app that utilizes a log. I've placed a file entitled "log.txt" in the "Raw" resource folder. I have figured out how to open it to an inputstream using `openRawResource`, however I am not sure how to open it so I can use `PrintWriter` with it.

I have also tried accessing a file pre-created on the target device, but have not succeeded.

If someone could explain to me either how to open the resource file to a PrintWriter, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however I am not sure how to open it so I can use PrintWriter with it.

You can't. Resources are read-only at runtime. You are welcome to use that `InputStream` to write a copy of the resource's contents to a file on the filesystem (e.g., on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)), though.

Comment: How can I access the internal resources? I tried this earlier but was unable to.

Comment: @EthanKershner: I do not know what you mean by "the internal resources", or by "access" in this context. You already know about `openRawResource()`. If by "internal resources" you mean internal storage, call `getFilesDir()` on any `Context` to get a `File` object pointing at a directory that you can write to. From there, it is standard Java file I/O.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's what I meant. 

Thanks.