# How can I write an Object to my raw folder file

Tags: java, android, serialization, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

This is my serializable class.

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
private String name;
private String surname;
private int age;


public Person(String name,String surname,int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {

    this.surname = surname;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public String toString(){
return name + " "+surname+" "+age;
}
}
```

I am trying to write a Person class to a raw folder using FileOutputStream, but nothing is working. Can't create a FileOutputStream, to get the raw folder file.

Also I tried a FileOutputStream.

```
 FileOutputStream fos = getBaseContext().openFileOutput(
     "android.resource://com.cpt.sample/raw/text.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Why do you want to write inside `raw/` folder?

Comment: Any data present in the "res" folder is not writable. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618511/how-to-write-a-file-in-raw-folder-in-android

Comment: So where can I save the file for later use ? @m0skit0

Comment: So where should i put the file ? @MiguelBenitez

Comment: I think @Dharvik shah already give you the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change resource file. They are static at run-time. you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36830013/5432730).

And to put file at runtime you can use :

- internal storage (or)
- external storage

and to get this directories use : `Environment.getExternalFilesDir()`

Fore more information go [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).